# xcb_get_geometry_reply returns slightly larger window geometry then the real window on Gnome

Tags: x11, gnome, xcb

I have a method that's supposed to return position and size of the active window. Works find on Plasma for example but on Gnome the geometry is a little bit larger then the real window as seen on this screenshot:

[image]

I'm using `xcb_get_geometry_reply` to fetch the window information. Any idea what might be causing such behavior and how to mitigate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea what might be causing such behavior

I think the values that you get are correct. You can see a shadow around the window (at least on the right and bottom side, but I bet that shadow is also present on the left and top). I bet that shadow is implemented by having a larger window and then making parts of it transparent.

So, the values that you get are correct, because they also include the shadow.

> and how to mitigate it?

You could run `xprop -frame` and/or `xprop` in a terminal and then click on the window. Does GTK set some property that contain the size of the shadow? (I do not know the answer to this question; this is just a guess) (Is this even a GTK window?)

Comment: I'm suspecting the shadow too and yes, that's the question, how to find out what part of the geometry is the shadow and what the actual window. 

Just run `xprop -frame` for a random window and then compared screenshots of the window with and without the border and as it looks like the `_GTK_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL)`  has four values that are the offset on the left, right, top and bottom site of the window, so that might be it. Any idea how to query this value from code?

Comment: It looks like this could actually work. I have the windowId already and by calling `xprop -id <WindowId>` I get the data that I require. 
Still would be nice to do it somehow directly from code without invoking an application but if there is no other way then this will do it.

Comment: Since you are already using XCB (the question was about `xcb_get_geometry`), you can just use `xcb_get_property` to query the property. Before that, you need `xcb_intern_atom(c, "_GTK_FRAME_EXTENTS", strlen("_GTK_FRAME_EXTENTS"))` to get the atom. Then `xcb_get_property(c, 0, win, atom, XCB_ATOM_CARDINAL, 0, 42)` (the 42 is just a random guess, it might be that 4 is better but I am always confused whether this counts bytes or values).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm going to try it, looks better then what I have here at the moment with calling xprop.

Comment: Got something working with following code https://pastebin.com/n5kZH6kM
But the output is a bit strange, it has the length of 16: https://i.imgur.com/Toz67If.png

Am I doing something wrong or missing?

Comment: Instead of `(char*)xcb_get_property_value(reply)`, you want to cast to `uint32_t` and get the four values from that (each 32 bit value needs four bytes and 4*4=16).

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Uli Schlachter points in the right direction I got a working solution in case someone comes across this post.

```
auto connection = QX11Info::connection();
auto atom_cookie = xcb_intern_atom(connection, 0, strlen("_GTK_FRAME_EXTENTS"), "_GTK_FRAME_EXTENTS");
ScopedCPointer<xcb_intern_atom_reply_t> atom_reply(xcb_intern_atom_reply(connection, atom_cookie, nullptr));

if (!atom_reply.isNull()) {
    auto cookie = xcb_get_property(connection, 0, windowId, atom_reply->atom, XCB_ATOM_CARDINAL, 0, 4);
    ScopedCPointer<xcb_get_property_reply_t> reply(xcb_get_property_reply(connection, cookie, nullptr));

    if (!reply.isNull()) {
        int length = xcb_get_property_value_length(reply.data());
        if (length != 0) {
            auto gtkFrameExtents = static_cast<uint32_t*>(xcb_get_property_value(reply.data()));
            auto left = gtkFrameExtents[0];
            auto right = gtkFrameExtents[1];
            auto top = gtkFrameExtents[2];
            auto bottom = gtkFrameExtents[3];
        }
    }
}
```